# cant disable third-party repositories for upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

I Can't disable third-party repositories for upgrading.

I've tried everything including "software and updates" [other software] checked off all.
Also tried `apt-get install -f`as terminal suggests.
also tried `sudo software-properties-gtk`

This is what keeps coming up no matter what I try.

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-33-generic_3.16.0-33.44_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic_3.16.0-34.47_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-36-generic_3.16.0-36.48_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-37-generic_3.16.0-37.51_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-38-generic_3.16.0-38.52_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-signed-image-3.16.0-33-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-33-generic (= 3.16.0-33.44) but 3.16.0-33.44~14.04.1 is installed
 linux-signed-image-3.16.0-34-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic (= 3.16.0-34.47) but 3.16.0-34.47~14.04.1 is installed
 linux-signed-image-3.16.0-36-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-36-generic (= 3.16.0-36.48) but 3.16.0-36.48~14.04.1 is installed
 linux-signed-image-3.16.0-37-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-37-generic (= 3.16.0-37.51) but 3.16.0-37.51~14.04.1 is installed
 linux-signed-image-3.16.0-38-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-38-generic (= 3.16.0-38.52) but 3.16.0-38.52~14.04.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

The package system is broken

Check if you are using third-party repositories. If so, disable them, because they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore, run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

linux-signed-image-3.16.0-33-generic: Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-33-generic (= 3.16.0-33.44) but 3.16.0-33.44~14.04.1 is installed
                                      Depends: linux-image-extra-3.16.0-33-generic (= 3.16.0-33.44) but 3.16.0-33.44 is installed
linux-signed-image-3.16.0-34-generic: Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic (= 3.16.0-34.47) but 3.16.0-34.47~14.04.1 is installed
                                      Depends: linux-image-extra-3.16.0-34-generic (= 3.16.0-34.47) but 3.16.0-34.47 is installed
linux-signed-image-3.16.0-36-generic: Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-36-generic (= 3.16.0-36.48) but 3.16.0-36.48~14.04.1 is installed
                                      Depends: linux-image-extra-3.16.0-36-generic (= 3.16.0-36.48) but 3.16.0-36.48 is installed
linux-signed-image-3.16.0-37-generic: Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-37-generic (= 3.16.0-37.51) but 3.16.0-37.51~14.04.1 is installed
                                      Depends: linux-image-extra-3.16.0-37-generic (= 3.16.0-37.51) but 3.16.0-37.51 is installed
linux-signed-image-3.16.0-38-generic: Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-38-generic (= 3.16.0-38.52) but 3.16.0-38.52~14.04.1 is installed
                                      Depends: linux-image-extra-3.16.0-38-generic (= 3.16.0-38.52) but 3.16.0-38.52 is installed
```

Please help.

Comment: Unfortunately, the solution I presented doesn't work, so I deleted it.
In this case, I know what's wrong but I don't know how to fix it (cleanly).
Sorry OP. :(

Comment: @NormanLi What was your solution?

Comment: Basically clearing APT's cache and then retrying. :) (`sudo apt-get clean`)

Answer (score 0):

Remove all files from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`:

```
mkdir ~/sources.list.d
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d ~/
```

Remove

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list ~/
```

Start `software-properties-gtk`

```
gksudo software-properties-gtk
```

Check the following properties (sorry for vivid in my screenshots). Thus, the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` is created again.

[image]

[image]

Install `aptitude`

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

and run with

```
sudo aptitude install -f
```

and fix your problems.